# Is it possible to use anything other than GridLayout on Eclipse preference pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, swt, preferences

The following simple preference page fails with a `ClassCastException`:

```
@Override
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    List list = new List(container, SWT.NONE);
    return container;
}
```

The same code works fine with a regular SWT application. If I replace the `FillLayout` with a `GridLayout`, it works, but that doesn't satisfy me. Is there no way to use a `FillLayout` or `RowLayout` in Eclipse preference pages?

**Edit:**
I'm very sorry, I did not pay enough attention when preparing the example. The above code does indeed work fine. In my code, I returned the list, not the container (!). For some reason, that worked in normal SWT, but it's really nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be doable, maybe two tricks, one is to try this:

```
container.setLayoutData(new GridData(...));
```

And if that doesn't do the trick, then adding first one container with GridLayout and inside that FillOut should definatedly work.

Bit strange anyhow, I would have assumed that code provided would have worked, but try setting that layoutdata.

Comment: I'm sorry, please read my edit above. I'll accept your answer anyways because you said it should work and you were right :)